# Angular: How ng-show works

Tags: angularjs

Here is a small example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title>Hello World, AngularJS</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    Write some text in textbox:
    <input type="text" ng-model="sometext" />

    <h1 ng-show="sometext">Hello {{ sometext }}</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

When the program runs, `<h1>` tag is not showing because **sometext** returns false to **ng-show**.

Why does **sometext** return false? Because sometext is empty or unassigned?

Comment: yes, you answered your own question there. null, undefined, 0 all are falsy

Comment: Just a note: don't use version 1.0.7 of Angular. It's completely obsolete. Current version is 1.5.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your code you can see it working. I added a h2 element with the actual value of sometext and you can see that it is an empty string which evaluates to false in JavaScript.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title>Hello World, AngularJS</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    Write some text in textbox:
    <input type="text" ng-model="sometext" />

    <h1 ng-show="sometext">Hello {{sometext}}</h1>
    <h2>Actual String {{sometext}}</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ngShow` directive shows or hides the given HTML element based on the expression provided to the `ngShow` attribute. The element is shown or hidden by removing or adding the `.ng-hide` CSS class onto the element. The `.ng-hide` CSS class is predefined in AngularJS and sets the display style to none (using an !important flag).

After the ngShow expression evaluates to a truthy value and just before contents are set to visible `.ng-hide` class is removed and if expression evaluates to a non truthy value i.e. 0, false or null then `.ng-hide` class is added.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Mahesh i asked a different thing probably u did not read my post properly. i did not ask the definition of ngShow.